# installing IBM Tivoli Directory Server

Tags: tivoli

I am trying to install IBM Tivoli Directory Server, but I am getting these errors,
I am using Centos7 and trying to install Tivoli 7.4
from the below exceptions "cannot run program", it seems like a permission issue while I am using **the root user**.

### the exceptions:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/ismp001/db2lscmd.sh" (in
> directory "/tmp/ismp001"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file
> or directory
> at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:471)
> at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:605)
> at com.installshield.util.Java2ProcessExec.processExec(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2,
> No such file or directory
> at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:265) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/ismp001/idsversion" (in
> directory "/tmp/ismp001"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file
> or directory
> at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:471)
> at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:605)
> at com.installshield.util.Java2ProcessExec.processExec(Unknown Source) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
> "/tmp/ismp001/ChkUseridsldapExists.sh" (in directory "/tmp/ismp001"):
> java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
> at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:471)
> at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:605)
> at com.installshield.util.Java2ProcessExec.processExec(Unknown Source) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
> "/tmp/ismp001/installDB2.sh" (in directory "/tmp/ismp001"):
> java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
> at java.lang.Throwable.(Throwable.java:80)
> at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:450)
> at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:605)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736) Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or
> directory
> at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:265)
> at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:101)
> at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:464)
> ... 6 more java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/ismp001/installLinuxGSKit.ksh" (in directory "/tmp/ismp001"):
> java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
> at java.lang.Throwable.(Throwable.java:80)
> at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:450)
> at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:605)
> at com.installshield.wizard.service.system.GenericSystemUtilService.executeProcess(Unknown
> Source) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
> "/tmp/ismp001/configAppSrv.sh" (in directory "/tmp/ismp001"):
> java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
> at java.lang.Throwable.(Throwable.java:80)
> at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:450) Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such
> file or directory
> at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:265)

Comment: That's not a permission issue. It's trying to run various scripts in  `/tmp/ismp001/` which simply aren't there.